# Reducing SAT to a P problem in polinomial time

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np, 3-sat

Does reducing SAT in polynomial time to a P problem would mean that P = NP?

Comment: The answer to this question is clear when one has a proper understanding of P, NP and NP-hardness reduction. This can be obtained by reading standard resources, such as the one refered to as a duplicate.

Comment: So... the answer is yes?